# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://bucket/sftp/poc/creds/abc-sdc-sa-key.json'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to read .json file which stores credentials in GCS using below code in cloud function.

```
from google.cloud import storage
import json
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(r'gs://bucket/sftp/poc/creds/abc-sdc-sa-key.json')
```

I am getting this error, I'm not sure why:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://bucket/sftp/poc/creds/abc-sdc-sa-key.json'
```

Comment: my thoughts - a) your system doesn't automagically know what gs:// type of path is and that it needs to go and get the data from the google cloud storage. If the file is public you can use  its https url to access it. b) if the file is a service account key to access cloud storage, you might have a chicken and the egg problem.

Comment: @jabbson. thanks for response . if i put these .json file in local machine and run the code in python . its perfectly works fine

Comment: @Y2Jepic Could you put as an answer to the post the solution/workaround you found to your issue? It would be helpful for other members of the community who are facing similar problems.